# Mudar valor data-atribute não funciona com Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Segue código:

**JS:**

```
$("#id_notification_count").data("count", 10);
```

**Html:**

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle">
    <i id="id_notification_count" data-count="3" class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell notification-icon"></i>
</a>
```

O código de JS deveria funcionar ... e aqui tenho um exemplo em jsfiddle [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/pcwLpes4/6/).

Porque a linha `$("#id_notification_count").data("count", 10);` não funciona ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os `data-custom` são atributos especiais definidos pelo `HTML5`, mas como qual quer elemento eles podem armazenar apenas `strings`.

Por um outro lado, a coleção interna do jQuery, que é acessível pelo método `.data()` pode vir à armazenar qual quer tipo de dado, inclusive objetos complexos com referencia circular.

Então por comodidade, o `jQuery` optou por carregar os valores dos `data-custom` como valores iniciais da sua coleção interna, mas veja, até neste ponto temos algumas inconsistências.:

```js
var valores = $(".valores");
console.log(valores.data("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="A" />
<input class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="B" />
<input class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="C" />
<input class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="D" />
```

Então, o `.data("value")`deveria retornar `"A"` ou `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`? Afinal você precisar lembrar que o `jQuery` é um `wrapper` para uma coleção de `DOM`, enquanto o `data-custom` está à apenas à um elemento `DOM`.

agora vamos à um caso com o uso de objeto com referencia circular.:

```js
var valores = $(".valores");
console.log(valores.data("value"));

var objetoA = {};
var objetoB = {};
objetoA.Gemeo = objetoB;
objetoB.Gemeo = objetoA;

valores.data("value", objetoA);
console.log(objetoA);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="A" />
```

Qual valor deveria ser exibido no `data-value` neste caso? uma `string` com a  representação do objeto em `JSON`? isto poderia travar o `Browser` ;D

Por fim, a propriedade `.data()` é anterior à definição dos `data-custom` do `HTML5`, porém o `jQuery` evoluiu para fazer uso deles na sua implementação, até para que fosse possível criar plugins com inicialização automática configuráveis apartir dos atributos.

Em todo caso o `JavaScript` define à sua propria forma de acessar os `data-custom`, e esta permite a edição dos mesmos.

```js
var valores = document.querySelectorAll(".valores");
[].forEach.call(valores, function (valor, indice) {
  var valorOld = valor.dataset.value;
  valor.dataset.value = valor.dataset.value.charCodeAt(0);
  var valorNew = valor.dataset.value;
  console.log(`O elemento #${valor.id} tinha o valor ${valorOld} e foi alterado para ${valorNew}`);
});
```

```html
<input id="elemA" class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="A" />
<input id="elemB" class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="B" />
<input id="elemC" class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="C" />
<input id="elemD" class="valores" type="hidden" data-value="D" />
```

note, que ao utilizar a propriedade `dataset` o valor dos `data-custom` foram alterados.

Comment: Tobias Mesquita, muito boa a sua reposta . Nice !